# ConTeXt: Is there a package or functionality similar to the LaTeX mwe package?

Tags: graphics, context, mwe

I would like to post questions here concerning [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) and graphics.

However, I cannot find a minimum working example package for ConTeXt like [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer)'s [`mwe package`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe) for LaTeX. Nothing alike appears on [the ConTeXt module and packages list](http://modules.contextgarden.net/).

Is there a MWE package or similar built-in functionality for ConTeXT?

It would be great to see here an example of a Context MWE with graphics.

Comment: Have a look at [``meta-imp-dum.mkiv``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/meta-imp-dum.mkiv). All you have to do is to place the statement ``\useMPlibrary[dum]`` at the top of your document and then use figure names that do not resolve to real image files. If you need further functionality your chances of a good answer will rise if you describe what exactly it is that you wish (image!). You cannot presuppose that Context users will be familiar with any Latex package.

Comment: Also, have a look at the files in the [``sample/`` directory](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/tree/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/sample). They exist in every Context installation for demonstrational purposes. E.g. use ``\input knuth`` if you need some dummy text, ``\externalfigure[cow]`` for an image etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. The `mwe` package is just provides a bunch of images. By default, the package is located in `$TEXMF/tex/latex/` subtree, so these images are not found by ConTeXt. If the package is repackaged so that the images are in `$TEXMF/tex/generic` then the images can also be used in ConTeXt (see next point).
2. ConTeXt provides a few sample images in `$TEXMF/tex/context/sample` directory. These include `cow.pdf`, `hacker.jpg`, `mill.png`, and `spider.eps`. By default, ConTeXt does not search in the `$TEXMF` tree for images. To change that use (see [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Specifying_image_directories) for details)

   ```
   \setupexternalfigures
       [location={local,global,default}]

   \starttext
   \startcombination[3*1]
      {\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=0.3\textwidth]}    {cow.pdf}
      {\externalfigure[hacker.jpg][width=0.3\textwidth]} {hacker.jpg}
      {\externalfigure[mill.png][width=0.3\textwidth]}   {mill.png}
   \stopcombination
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]
3. ConTeXt provides a MP library `dum` to create dummy images. To use that simply add `\useMPlibrary[dum]`. Then, a dummy figure is drawn whenever you call `\externalfigure` with a filename that does not exist. The convention is to use `\externalfigure[dummy]`. For example:

   ```
   \useMPlibrary[dum]

   \starttext
   \startcombination[3*1]
     {\externalfigure[dummy][width=0.3\textwidth]}{Dummy figure}
     {\externalfigure[dummy][width=0.3\textwidth]}{Dummy figure}
     {\externalfigure[dummy][width=0.3\textwidth]}{Dummy figure}
   \stopcombination
   \stoptext
   ```

   gives

   [image]

   The colors are chosen at random.
4. ConTeXt can download images from the web, so you can use any image that you want. For example

   ```
   \starttext
   \startcombination[3*1]
     {\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/400/600][method=jpg]}{One cat}
     {\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/500/600][method=jpg]}{Another cat}
     {\externalfigure[http://placekitten.com/g/600/600][method=jpg]}{And one more}
   \stopcombination
   \stoptext
   ```

   which gives

   [image]

   The `method=jpg` is needed because the image name does not have an extension. The images are downloaded and stored in the cache directory. This means that if you really want the images provided by the `mwe` package, you can use:

   ```
   \starttext
   \startcombination[3*1]
     {\externalfigure[http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a.pdf][width=0.3\textwidth]}{A}
     {\externalfigure[http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-b.pdf][width=0.3\textwidth]}{B}
     {\externalfigure[http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-c.pdf][width=0.3\textwidth]}{C}
   \stopcombination
   \stoptext
   ```

   which gives

   [image]